# Editing a tag wiki that is nothing but the excerpt all over again

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

A while ago, I attempted to edit a tag wiki that simply restates its own excerpt without actually expanding on it meaningfully. Given that tags can survive just fine with nothing but excerpts, it seemed reasonable enough to simply erase the wiki and leave the excerpt to handle it; anyone wishing to improve the wiki would do well to start from scratch anyway rather than incrementally editing something so basically redundant.

This was [uniformly disagreed with](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6566905), though, so I appear to have some mistaken reasoning somewhere. What *should* I have done in such a case?

<sub>*Note that I discovered this just now while searching through old suggestions for rejections.*</sub>

Comment: I think that emptying out the tag wiki when it is perfectly fine would be a red flag for me as well, if I were reviewing your edit. If there's no reason to remove it, why remove it?

Answer (score 8):

Well, just because tags can survive without wikis doesn't mean that it's okay to just delete them if they already exist.

If a tag doesn't have a wiki (or it doesn't have a good one), it typically means that it's not a very popular tag and so no one has enough invested in it to put forth the effort to create a wiki.

If I'm an editor looking at that edit, I'd say to myself, "this guy is just erasing a wiki that, while not providing much information about the tag, does a rudimentary job of categorizing it. Why should I grant him 2 reputation for knowing where the backspace key is?"

I can see why you'd think deleting the wiki would be warranted here, but it doesn't do much for the tag. If you're going to rewrite it, go ahead and wipe it clean, but otherwise, it's best to just leave it alone or fix it up a bit.

Comment: I guess my idea was mostly that it could be better to signal future editors "this is a blank slate, you'll need to come up with a new framework to make it useful" than to leave it alone.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Maybe, but if you're not willing to do it yourself, then maybe it's better to give the two rep to someone who is (or to let someone with tag wiki edit privileges wipe it).